# Can I navigate to my PSDrive without typing "cd"?

Tags: .net, powershell

In Powershell I am defining a new PSDrive called `test`.  But when I type `test:` at the console it throws an error.  If I type `cd test:` it works fine.

Shouldn't I be able to navigate to the `test` drive just by typing `test:`?

```
PS> New-PSDrive -name test -psprovider FileSystem -root C:\test

WARNING: column "CurrentLocation" does not fit into the display and was removed.

Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----
test                            128.42 FileSystem    C:\test


PS> test:
The term 'test:' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:6
    + test: <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (test::String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to define a function called "test:" that calls `Set-Location test:` like so:

```
function test: {Set-Location test:}
```

To see that this is also how the other drive names are working enter the following commands:

```
cd function:
dir
```

You will see that the other drive aliases have been mapped to their proper command using a function. So `C:` is just a function name that calls `Set-Location C:`.

Btw, the `cd` command is just an alias for `Set-Location`.